# Query date and show in HTML date input

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

I have an HTML form that has a date input as below

```html
<div class="col-sm" id="old">
  <label for="startDateOld">Current Start Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDateOlds" name="startDateOld" readonly value="<?php echo $startDate; ?>">
</div>
```

When the page loads, it is actually querying the `startDate` into a php variable called `$startDate`. I need this `$startDate` to be shown in my date input field. But somehow it is not showing anything.

In my MySQL database, this date is a `timestamp`. I format it the following `php` way to match the HTML `date` input

```
$startDate = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($startDate));
```

But somehow it is not loading the date value although `$startDate` contains a value in `YYYY/MM/DD` format which matches HTML date input format.

Does anyone know why I can't show the date value?

Comment: As per input type date [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date], 
You can set a default value for the input with a date inside the value attribute, like so:
`<input type="date" value="2017-06-01">`
The date is formatted according to ISO8601, described in Format of a valid date string in Date and time formats used in HTML.
Check for details [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Format_of_a_valid_date_string]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML date inputs need to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` form, not `YYYY/MM/DD` (see the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Format_of_a_valid_date_string)). So change your:

```
$startDate = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($startDate));
```

to

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate));
```

and it should work fine.

Demo of `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY/MM/DD` format in HTML:

```html
<div class="col-sm" id="old">
  <label for="startDateOld">Current Start Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDateOlds" name="startDateOld" readonly value="2020-01-16"><br/>
  <label for="startDateOld2">Current Start Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDateOlds" name="startDateOld2" readonly value="2020/01/16">
</div>
```